# Apache - map specific urls to different document roots

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is it possible, in some way, to map urls in Apache like -

- `example.com` to `/var/www/app/public`
- `example.com/api` to `/var/www/api/public`

I just don't want to use subdomains, and i can't mix the app and api together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, by just using symlink, from `/var/www/app/public/api` to `/var/www/api/public`.